# Imap Error while checking email in python

Tags: python-3.x, email, gmail, imap, imaplib

I am using Python 3.7.7 and wanted to check my gmail emails with this code:

```py
import smtplib
import time
import imaplib
import email
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
        mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
mail.login("tanmay.noreply@gmail.com","mypassword")
mail.select('inbox')

type, data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
mail_ids = data[0]

id_list = mail_ids.split()   
first_email_id = int(id_list[0])
latest_email_id = int(id_list[-1])


for i in range(latest_email_id,first_email_id, -1):
    typ, data = mail.fetch(i, '(RFC822)' )

    for response_part in data:
        if isinstance(response_part, tuple):
            msg = email.message_from_string(response_part[1])
            email_subject = msg['subject']
            email_from = msg['from']
            print('From : ') + email_from + '\n'
            print('Subject : ')+ email_subject + '\n'
```

But I am getting this error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jeeva/Desktop/Tanmay_new/python/stackimap.py", line 19, in read_email_from_gmail
    typ, data = mail.fetch(i, '(RFC822)' )
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\imaplib.py", line 534, in fetch
    typ, dat = self._simple_command(name, message_set, message_parts)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\imaplib.py", line 1196, in _simple_command
    return self._command_complete(name, self._command(name, *args))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\imaplib.py", line 961, in _command
    data = data + b' ' + arg
TypeError: can't concat int to bytes
```

Please help me. I found the python 2 snippet in [this website](https://codehandbook.org/how-to-read-email-from-gmail-using-python/) and converted to python 3.

Comment: try `mail.fetch(str(i), 'RFC822')`. Also use `message_from_bytes` with python 3.

Comment: Try to use libs, for example https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that the author likes imap_tools library, a complete response:

High level lib short example:

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, AND

# get list of email subjects from INBOX folder
with MailBox('imap.mail.com').login('test@mail.com', 'password', 'INBOX') as mailbox:
    subjects = [msg.subject for msg in mailbox.fetch()]
```

https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

- Parsed email message attributes
- Query builder for searching emails
- Work with emails in folders (copy, delete, flag, move, seen)
- Work with mailbox folders (list, set, get, create, exists, rename, delete, status)